# MATLAB vectorization to create a matrix

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to create a matrix like

```
[1 2;
 1 3;
 1 4;
 1 5;
 2 3;
 2 4;
 2 5;
 3 4;
 3 5;
 4 5 ]
```

when the size is 5. I aim to have sizes greater than 100. How can I create a matrix like this using vertorization in MATLAB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for binomial coefficients, so use the built-in [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) command. For example, the matrix in your question can be generated by:

```
A = nchoosek(1:5, 2)
```

This results in:

```
A =
     1     2
     1     3
     1     4
     1     5
     2     3
     2     4
     2     5
     3     4
     3     5
     4     5
```

Comment: I completely forgot you can input a vector. +1

Answer (score 2):

One solution:

```
[r,c]=find(tril(ones(N),-1));
result = [c,r];
```

As a bonus, you can get the number of rows in such matrix with

```
nrows = nchoosek(N,2);
```

Comment: I actually liked your first answer, because it is how I do other parts of the computation.